# Windsor - how to register against two interfaces but separate registration lines

Tags: castle-windsor

I currently register a large number of classes using this one-line syntax:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IWidgetViewModel>().WithService.Base().LifestyleSingleton());
```

One of these classes implements both `IWidgetViewModel` and a second interface that I would like to register, as I need to be able to inject the latter elsewhere. However adding a second registration line like the following obviously fails:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ISpecialViewModel>().ImplementedBy<MySpecialViewModel>().LifeStyle.Singleton);
```

(Windsor complains that `MySpecialViewModel`, which also implements `IWidgetViewModel`, is already registered).

How can I solve this? I'm using Castle Windsor 3.3 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I found that if I include that second line and add a name:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<ISpecialViewModel>().ImplementedBy<MySpecialViewModel>().LifeStyle.Singleton.Named("xyz");
```

It presumably makes the registration "unique" to prevent it from failing, and I'm still able to inject `ISpecialViewModel` where it's needed. (I'm a little surprised at this as I expected I'd always have to resolve it by name).